# A variation of the graph coloring problem

Tags: graphs, reference-request, colorings

Given a set of colors $M$ and a graph $G=(V,E)$. Allocate the colors to minimize the number edges with same color on the two vertices of the edge (i.e. minimize pairs of adjoining vertices with same color.).

This problem is different from standard [coloring problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring). Could someone please provide some literature where this problem is studied?

Comment: This is at least as hard as the graph coloring problem since a graph admits a $k$-coloring iff it can be colored with $k$ colors such that the number of adjacent vertices with the same color is $0$.

Comment: @G.Bach. That said, I'd be interested in seeing an algorithm. Right now it's late and I'm hungry, so I might be missing an obvious solution.

Comment: @RickDecker Naive approach would probably be binary search over $\{1,...,n\}$ colors, where for each $k \in \{1,...,n\}$ we check whether there is a $k$-coloring.

Comment: @G.Bach If the number of colors are higher than the maximum degree of the graph ($\Delta(G)<M$). Then I guess this problem is not hard right? Are you talking about the case ($\Delta(G)>M$)?

Comment: @triomphe Assuming we can solve your problem in polynomial time, then we could use that solution to solve the graph coloring problem ("does $G$ admit a $k$-coloring?") in polynomial time by checking whether $G$ can be colored using $M = [k]$ with $0$ conflicts.

Comment: @I was thinking When $\Delta(G)<M$ we can color in poly time. We start from one node, give a color, then give colors to all its neighbors and then move to any neighbor of the first node (neighbor is already colored) and assign colors to all it's neighbors and so on. Since $\Delta(G)<M$ we are guaranteed to have a color not used by all the neighbors at each step? Isn't this polynomial time? Please explain. Thanks

Comment: @triomphe If that worked, then graph coloring wouldn't be NP-hard, since it's obvious that you can't color with less than $\Delta(G)$ colors. The greedy approach to graph coloring doesn't work, it produces nonoptimal colorings for "bad" vertex orders.

Comment: @G.Bach So are you saying that a graph can't be colored with $M$ colors when $\Delta(G)<M$? I'm not trying to optimize. I am just trying to know if it is possible or not. Thanks.

Comment: @triomphe No, I'm saying that greedy coloring isn't guaranteed to produce an optimal coloring.

Comment: @triomphe I got confused, I mistook $\Delta(G)$ to be the clique number of $G$, which is of course wrong, so my comment saying that you can't color a graph with fewer than $\Delta(G)$ colors is wrong as well. You can indeed color any graph greedily with $\Delta(G) + 1$ colors the way you suggested. That doesn't make the problem any simpler in the general case, though.

Answer (score 3):

If $|M| = 2$, this is the [max-cut problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cut).

Comment: More generally, it is a special case of MAX-CSP, where only inequality constraints are allowed.